# Is it possible to prevent a project or its contents to be pushed accidentally into wrong repository

Tags: github, github-enterprise

About working with github: I am looking for something like a repo config file in the root directory in my project's working directory which says something like "This project belongs onto server private.github.com, if files are accidentally pushed onto another server or domain, fail with error."

This would protect against something like accidentally pushing private project contents onto public repository.

Something like this doable? Also, it should be automatic for every user so it cannot be something that the user themselves need to configure. Once they check out the project, the accident prevention should be in place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Gits hook to perform any automated checks while pushing or commiting: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Just create a shell script to check the repo and make it run with the git hooks.

Comment: Thanks. If clients can be either windows or linux etc. and we use eclipse git plugin to commit, do client hooks run independent of environment?